# dppx Or min-width combined query

Tags: breakpoint-sass

When I use `@include breakpoint(min-resolution: 1.5dppx)`,

I get this output:

`@media (min-resolution: 1.5dppx), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi)`

This shortcut is fine, but if I try to combine it with another query like this:

`@include breakpoint(min-resolution: 1.5dppx, 2050px)`

I get exactly the same (the last part is removed)

Then if I add some quotes:

`@include breakpoint("2050px, min-resolution 1.5dppx")`

I loose the cross-browser part: `@media (min-width: 2050px, min-resolution 1.5dppx)`

Is there a way to combine them successfully?

Answer (score 0):

When using `or` queries passed directly into the Breakpoint mixin, you need to wrap the whole query in parenthesis as the second argument to the Breakpoint mixin is `no-query`. You should be writing the following:

```
@include breakpoint((min-resolution 1.5dppx, 2050px)) {}
```

Take a look at this [SassMeister Example](http://sassmeister.com/gist/8869230) to see it working in action.